# Extending IdentityRole and IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using ASPNet Identity to implement security in my web application.

There is a requirements where in, I need to extend the IdentityRole and IdentityUser.

Here is my code to extend the IdentityUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual User  User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=CoreContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

My only problem is the IdentityRole

Comment: And your question / issue is...what exactly?  Please update your question with some more detail.

Comment: My Problem is I cannot extend the IdentityRole.

Comment: @RamonCruz - who says you can't extend the IdentityRole?

Answer (score 7):

To extend User , Update your `ApplicationUser` class(located in `IdentityModels.cs`) to

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, 
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    // Use a sensible display name for views:
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

}
```

To Extend Role , Create a class `ApplicationRole.cs`

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and Add the class inside `IdentityConfig.cs` file :

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(
        IRoleStore<ApplicationRole,string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(
            new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

Now clear the old database, Run the application and register a user. It will create 3 more fields(Address,City,State) in AspNetUsers table and one more field(Description) into AspNetRoles table. That's it.

For more info , go to the site :
[Extending Identity Role](http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/)

Comment: hi, did you impliment multi-tenant, I am having issues extending properties on [roles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43269854/6085193)

Comment: How would one do this in Asp.Net Core 3.1? There is no such file as IdentityConfig.cs...

Comment: @Stian Core , I don't think You can do this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit from IdentityRole in your application the same way that you do your IdentityUser. Why do you need to extend IdentityRole?
Please take a look at the following article which explains in detail what you are trying to do http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/13/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-Roles.aspx