# How to extend ASP IdentityRole in EF DbFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant, claims-based-identity

**How can I extend the IdentityRoles to work with an extended AspNetRoles Table?** in ASP MVC 5, with Identity 2.2 I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40336574/6085193) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429153/6085193) the answers do not help with DB First EF

**Step 1:** I extended/added the `CompanyId` & `DescRole` *(to make Role unique by company/tenant)*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]            // EXTENDED role table
    [Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,  // EXTENDED
    [CompanyId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,    // EXTENDED Company/Tenant
```

---

**Step 2**: Create new Role is an issue, now my create role fails, and I cannot find the extended `CompanyId`/`Desc` properties on the `IdentityRole` (its a `dbFirst EF strategy`)

---

```
 //Create ROle Class
 public ActionResult CreateRole(FormCollection collection)
 {
   try {

    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    // RoleStore
    // var newRole = new AspNetRoles();
    // ontext.Roles.Add(new ApplicationRole) { // not visible...
    context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
       {
            Name = collection["RoleName"],                    
       });
    context.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.Message = "Role created successfully !";
    ...

 //Extended Role Class
 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
 {
   public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
   public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string CompanyId { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ryXIU3QbldTC05T3p6Q3JqNDg

Comment: this project implements extending roles in ASP.NET Identity with Web API(Not in MVC). I believe you can achieve the same in mvc also.